# Dynamic query returning the query instead of the result

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Below is a part of my stored procedure that would convert my image into varbinary format so that it could be inserted in my table .The column of the table in which the image needs to be inserted is of varbinary datatype. This column is also a filestream column. The problem is that when I execute this query it returns me the query instead of the casted data

```
begin
Declare @Sql varchar(2000)
Declare @img varbinary(max)
Declare @productImageUrl varchar(max)='E:\3840x2400.jpg'

set @Sql= N'Declare @test VARBINARY(MAX);SELECT @test = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) 
FROM OPENROWSET(bulk '''+@productImageUrl+''', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS productImage PRINT @TEST'
--print @img
--print @sql
exec(@Sql)
end
```

Could anyone suggest me how to get the data instead of the query . Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks..

Comment: This is working fine on my machine.  Can you post the rest of the stored proc?

Comment: remove the print @test

Comment: "Command(s) completed successfully."

Comment: yes the command is getting completed successfully but I am not able to get the varbinary data

Comment: Hmm.  I replaced `SELECT @Test = ` with `INSERT INTO testtbl (test) SELECT ...` and it added a row to my test table with the binary data from the file I was testing with.

Comment: can you post the code ..please

Comment: I got that thanks for the help ..